# Advanced Format Alignment using parted

Tags: partitioning, format, sector-size

How do I align a Western Digital Advanced Format hard drive using minimal (4K) alignment when installing Ubuntu 11.04? Should I do it before installing via the LiveCD? If so, do I select to "Try Ubuntu" and then launch parted from the terminal? According to http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5655/~/how-to-install-a-wd-advanced-format-drive-on-a-non-windows-operating-system
it says to use: `parted -a optimal /dev/sda`.
So do I just launch terminal from LiveCD and type `sudo parted -a optimal /dev/sda` and then install Ubuntu normally?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to worry about it; it is handled automatically.